# Socket.io emit event multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, eventemitter

for example when i join room-1 then room-2 then room-3 and send message in room-3 that message will be emitted 3 times, when it should get sent just one time. i'm using vanilla JavaScript in the client side

server side

```
namespaces.forEach(namespace => {
  // join namespace
  io.of(namespace.endpoint).on('connection', socket => {

    console.log(`${socket.id} has joined the ${namespace.endpoint}`)
    socket.emit('nsRooms', {data: namespace.rooms})
    // Join room
    socket.on('joinRoom', async (payload, cb) => {
      const room = Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]
      room && socket.leave(room)
      socket.join(payload.data.roomName)
      const numOfMem = await io.of(payload.data.nsp).in(payload.data.roomName).allSockets()
      cb(Array.from(numOfMem).length)
    })

    socket.on('sendMessage', payload => {
      const room = Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]
      const nsp =  socket.nsp.name
      io.of(nsp).to(room).emit('updateMessage', payload)
    })

  })
})
```

client side \
Here is when i join rooms and send messages

```
function joinRoom(roomName) {
  form.removeEventListener('submit', e => submitMsg(e))
  nsSocket.emit('joinRoom', {data: {nsp: nsSocket.nsp, roomName}}, numberOfMember => {
    document.getElementById('current-room').innerHTML = `<span class="curr-room-text">${roomName}</span> <span class="curr-room-num-users">Users: ${numberOfMember}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>`
  })

  messages.innerHTML = ''
  nsSocket.on('updateMessage', payload => {
    messages.innerHTML += 
    `
        <li>
          <div class="user-image">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" />
          </div>
          <div class="user-message">
              <div class="user-name-time">rbunch <span>${new Date(Date.now()).toDateString()}</span></div>
              <div class="message-text">${payload.data}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
    `
  })
}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => submitMsg(e))

function submitMsg(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const msg = userMessage.value
  msg.length > 0 && nsSocket.emit('sendMessage', {data: msg})
  userMessage.value = ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `removeEventListener` needs to work with the exact same function reference that was registered, and `(e) => submitMsg(e)` creates a new lambda all the time. Which means that each time you join a room, a new event handler will be added, without removing the old one.

I created a quick sample app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bhxdhd?file=index.js) with the following code that would fix your issue. If you click 'Join some room' three times and then click 'Send message', only one console.log will appear (expand the console on the right hand side to see the result).

```
const testBtn = document.getElementById('joinRoom');
const form = document.getElementById('chatForm');

testBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.removeEventListener('submit', submitMsg);

  // ... some other code

  form.addEventListener('submit', submitMsg);
});

submitMsg = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('submitMsg() called!');

  return false;
}
```